# When using AngularJS filter service in JavaScript, why are the parameters in closed parenthesis of their own?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am used to seeing parameters being passed to functions within one set of parenthesis. I'm used to this from C# and also from starting to learn JavaScript.

Here is one example:

```
functionName(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3) {
    code to be executed
}
```

But I came across this AngularJS example where using filters from the JavaScript code is done by passing parameters in a parenthesis of their own.

```
$scope.filteredText = $filter('uppercase')($scope.originalText);
```

I would expect the parameter to be passed as:

```
$scope.filteredText = $filter('uppercase', $scope.originalText);
```

Why it it passed in a parenthesis of its own instead? What kind of syntax is that? Is it JavaScript or is it AngularJS specific?

Comment: `$filter('uppercase')` returns a function that is then invoked with the argument `$scope.originalText`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`($scope.originalText)` is not a second parameter to the `$filter` function.

The `$filter('uppercase')` function [returns another function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter) and you are passing `$scope.originalText` as a parameter to this returned function. It's just a shortened version of:

```
var f = $filter('uppercase');
f($scope.originalText);
```